# Terminating second thread in micropython on Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, rp2040

I use both cores of RP2040 chip. Main one runs main loop and second handles LCD display.
I start second one on the thread like

```
_thread.start_new_thread(taskLCD, (100,0.5))
```

where taskLCD updates LCD every half os second.

Sometimes when I restart program second core is still working and there is a message:

**OSError: core1 in use**

Is there way to kill this second core process in advance and elimiate this message?
The only way to stop it is to entirely shutdown/depower chip. But, in this case, all info is lost and I do not know what had happen, what had caused the error.

Comment: I really don't know, but it looks like a `thread_exit()` is supposed to shut down the thread.  Or maybe `thread_get_ident()` will give you a way to determine if there is / is-not an existing thread? These are the things I would try, anyway. Or have taskLCD set a variable to indicate that it doesn't need to be restarted?

Comment: I would go with idea of variable that indicates that tread should die. But it will take time. Issue is - I start new main thread from scratch but it should assume that old core1 is still running.

Answer (score 1):

Connect `RUN` pin to `GND`, which will reset the board and also stops another core